# generate different captcha in one session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, captcha

how i want to generate a captcha that is different with each other in one session?

for example :
i have a application form that has a captcha before the user can proceed to next step. the problem is, if I open another same application form in the new windows tab, it will generate the same captcha as the first application form. what i need is different captcha value.

help me with solving this problem please...tq

i'm using asp.net.

here the sample code

to generate code

```
private string GenerateRandomCode()
{
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        s = String.Concat(s, random.Next(10).ToString());
    return s;
}
```

to generate captcha image

```
namespace OneStepContactMe.Layouts.OneStepContactMe
{
    public partial class captchapage : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["Map"] == null)
                { 
                    Session["Map"] = GenerateRandomCode();      
                }
                // Create a CAPTCHA image using the text stored in the Session object.
                CaptchaImage ci = new CaptchaImage(this.Session["Map"].ToString(), 200, 50, "Century Schoolbook");

                // Change the response headers to output a JPEG image.
                this.Response.Clear();
                this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

                // Write the image to the response stream in JPEG format.
                ci.Image.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                // Dispose of the CAPTCHA image object.
                ci.Dispose(); 
            }
            else {
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generate random 6 digit
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> string of 6 digits </returns>
        private string GenerateRandomCode()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                s = String.Concat(s, random.Next(10).ToString());
            return s;
        }

        //to allow anonymous access to this pages
        protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreInit(e);
            this.MasterPageFile = "/_catalogs/masterpage/MyCorridor.MemberArea.v1.master";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Random local variable to member field.
e.g.

```
public partial class captchapage : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
{
    private Random random = new Random();
}
```

Comment: although good advice in general, this won't help here: in ASP.NET the class is recreated for each request, so there will still be a new `Random` for each request.